# How to use excludes for a specific rule in rubocop.yml

Tags: ruby, rubocop

```
Metrics/BlockLength:
  Excludes:
    - '/app/**'
```

I have this .rubocop.yml, I am expecting rubocop to not to complain only for whatever files under app regarding the block length. But it still complains, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
Metrics/BlockLength:
  Exclude:
    - "app/**/*"
```

http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#includingexcluding-files

Comment: Actually it's Exclude not Excludes